# How to automatically start and stop a compute instance to execute Azure Machine Learning pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I've been following [this notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-setup-schedule-for-a-published-pipeline.ipynb) to schedule the execution of some code every hour. It makes a schedule and creates the pipelines. The problem is that if the computer instance is not running, the pipeline is just queued and waiting for it to run.

Is there a way to automatically run a compute instance when a pipeline is triggered within Azure Machine Learning, as well as stop them when the pipeline is completed?

I need to do it within the AzureML Studio platform because that is the only thing external Data Scientists have access to. I can't use clusters because some of their behaviors cause issues with the code.

I can schedule an instance to become active approximately at the same time as the schedule, but I want to do it in the code, so the scripts can run when they are up, as well as shut down the instance when the pipeline run is over.

Comment: > I can't use clusters because some of their behaviors cause issues with the code.. 

can you clarify what issues are you facing? Seems like clusters are the right option to go for even though a MSFT customer care person feels otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to manage the compute instance, you can set it up either in studio or in script.

1. in studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python#create-a-schedule-in-studio
2. with Resource Manage Template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python#create-a-schedule-with-a-resource-manager-template
3. in script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-manage-compute-instance?tabs=python#setup-script